# getting mql error from jquery, but not in query editor

Tags: jquery, freebase

I have a query that works correctly [in the query editor](http://tinyurl.com/a6qg8lg), but fails when loading [in a page](http://will.tip.dhappy.org/lib/mimis/html) ([here's the script](http://will.tip.dhappy.org/lib/mimis/freebase/jquery)). I get the error "Unique query may have at most one result. Got 2". I replaced the nulls in my query with empty arrays and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives an error in the query editor as well, but it's also returning results, which may be causing you to overlook the error code.

The problem is the top level of the query.  You need array there because it's returning multiple results.  Try wrapping the whole query in []